# Sendig data from view.py to forms.py

Tags: django

I am working on a django-project for practice arithmetics.
In a form the users may choice different difficulty levels. The options depends on the grade (in German "Jahrgang" = "jg").
In my view.py I can show the grade of the user ("print(user.jg)")
... and in the forms.py I can filter by the grade ("...filter(bis_jg__gte= 8")
... but how can I send the data (user.jg) to the filter (..filter(bis_jg__gte= **user.jg**)?
the forms.py:

```
def optionen(req, slug):
    kategorie = get_object_or_404(Kategorie, slug = slug)
    form = AuswahlForm(kategorie = kategorie)
    user = get_user(req.user)  
    print(user.jg) 
    zaehler = get_object_or_404(Zaehler, kategorie = kategorie, user = user)
    if req.method == 'POST':
        form = AuswahlForm(req.POST, kategorie = kategorie)
        if form.is_valid():
            optionen_text = ';'.join(map(str, form.cleaned_data['optionen']))
            if optionen_text == "":
                optionen_text = "keine"
        else:
            optionen_text = "keine"  
    else:
        anzahl = kategorie.auswahl_set.all().count()
        if anzahl>0:
            anzahl = Auswahl.objects.filter(bis_jg__gte = user.jg, bis_stufe__gte = user.stufe, kategorie = kategorie).count()
            if anzahl>0:
                return render(req, 'core/optionen.html', {'kategorie': kategorie, 'auswahl_form':form})
```

and the relevant part in views.py:

```
def optionen(req, slug):
    kategorie = get_object_or_404(Kategorie, slug = slug)
    form = AuswahlForm(kategorie = kategorie)
    user = get_user(req.user)  
    print(user.jg) 
    ...
    if req.method == 'POST':
        form = AuswahlForm(req.POST, kategorie = kategorie)
```

When I add "form = AuswahlForm(req.POST, kategorie = kategorie **, jg = user.jg**)" to views.py and "self.fields['optionen'].queryset = kategorie.auswahl_set.all().filter(bis_jg__gte= **jg**)" to forms.py I get the error: "Exception Value: name 'jg' is not defined"
Please notice: I am total beginner

Comment: What exactly does `get_user`?

Comment: get_user returns the data of the logged in user. (Sorry I am newbee) .. print(user.jg) returns the grad of the user - that works in my view.

Comment: why do you have two user models?

Comment: Is this a problem? (Where do you recognize this in my code? (I have one model for the login and one for more data - it is the best I could handle)

Comment: it is not a "problem" more quite inconvenient: you have to juggle with two models which generates some confusion, and also extra queries.

Comment: Maybe I should add more informations: Depending on the category of task (e.g. "addition" or task from "percentage calculation") there are different numbers of options - sometimes one ("addition"), or four ("percentage calculation") or even zero. And in this case (percentage) there are four options and they all are shown regardless of the grade of user. At grade 8 only one should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the user as parameter:

```
class AuswahlForm(forms.Form):
    optionen = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Kategorie.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required=False,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, kategorie=None, user=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kategorie is not None and user is not None:
            self.fields['optionen'].queryset = kategorie.auswahl_set.filter(
                bis_jg__gte=user.jg
            )
```

and then construct the form with:

```
def optionen(req, slug):
    kategorie = get_object_or_404(Kategorie, slug=slug)
    user = get_user(req.user)
    # …
    if req.method == 'POST':
        form = AuswahlForm(
            req.POST, request.FILES, kategorie=kategorie, user=user
        )
        # …
    else:
        form = AuswahlForm(kategorie=kategorie, user=user)
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: While most forms do not process media files, it is probably better to pass [**`request.FILES`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) to the form anyway, such that if you later add an extra media field, all views that use the form will indeed handle the files properly.

Comment: Thank you very much - it seems to work like it should! Maybe there comes a time when I will understand all of that (or even a little more) :)